# Authroize.Net Missing or invalid token for Accept Hosted iFrame page

Tags: php, token, authorize.net

Going nuts here with Authorize.Net extremely POOR documentation and error reporting.  I am trying to implement an `Accept Hosted` page to process credit cards.  I am able to generate the token but when I pass the token into the form (in the iFrame) I am getting an error `MISSING OR INVALID TOKEN`

The token is getting created without issue, but when trying to use it is when things go sideways.

And in the chrome inespector console I am getting two javascript errors returned:

```
ERROR TypeError: Cannot read property 'billTo' of null
ERROR TypeError: Cannot read property 'offsetHeight' of null
```

So, printing out my `$request` json I am able to validate my json object that is being passed to create the token is correct:

```
{
  "merchantAuthentication": {"name":"xxxxxxxx","transactionKey":"yyyyyyyyyyyy"},
  "clientId":"sdk-php-2.0.0-ALPHA",
  "refId":"ref1608564012",
  "transactionRequest": {
    "transactionType":"authCaptureTransaction",
    "amount":"360.00",
    "order":  {"invoiceNumber":"11373-0","description":"2020-11-01 bill for All Regions\/All Sites"},
    "customer":{"type":"business","id":"1002","email":"pjohnson@gmail.com"},
    "billTo":{"firstName":"Preston","lastName":"Johnson","company":"Backyard Grill","address":"123 Main St","city":"Tampa","state":"FL","zip":"33611","country":"USA"},
    "shipTo":{"firstName":"Preston","lastName":"Johnson","company":"Backyard Grill","address":"123 Main St","city":"Tampa","state":"FL","zip":"33611","country":"USA"}
  },
  "hostedPaymentSettings":
    {"setting":[
      {"settingName":"hostedPaymentReturnOptions","settingValue":"{ \"url\": \"https:\/\/portal.attendago.com\/adminInvoicePaid.html\", \"cancelUrl\": \"https:\/\/portal.attendago.com\/adminInvoicePay.html?invID=11373-0\", \"showReceipt\":true }"},
      {"settingName":"hostedPaymentButtonOptions","settingValue":"{ \"text\": \"Submit Payment\" }"},
      {"settingName":"hostedPaymentStyleOptions","settingValue":"{ \"bgColor\": \"#192a67\" }"},
      {"settingName":"hostedPaymentPaymentOptions","settingValue":"{ \"cardCodeRequired\":true, \"showCreditCard\":true, \"showBankAccount\":true }"},
      {"settingName":"hostedPaymentShippingAddressOptions","settingValue":"{ \"show\":false, \"required\":true }"},
      {"settingName":"hostedPaymentBillingAddressOptions","settingValue":"{ \"show\":true, \"required\":true }"},
      {"settingName":"hostedPaymentCustomerOptions","settingValue":"{ \"showEmail\":true, \"requiredEmail\":true, \"addPaymentProfile\":false }"},
      {"settingName":"hostedPaymentOrderOptions","settingValue":"{ \"show\":false }"},
      {"settingName":"hostedPaymentIFrameCommunicatorUrl","settingValue":"{ \"url\": \"https:\/\/portal.attendago.com\/adminInvoiceFrame.html\" }"}
  ]}
}
```

Here is my function to create the token:

```
function getCustomerToken($ss) {
    $ii = $ss['invoiceData'] ;
    if (isSet($ss['payMethods'])) {
      $pp = $ss['payMethods'] ;
    }
    
    ////////////////////////////////////////////////
    /// global objects needed for all transactions
    ////////////////////////////////////////////////
    
    // Create a merchantAuthenticationType, pulled from constants file
    $merchantAuthentication = new AnetAPI\MerchantAuthenticationType();
    $merchantAuthentication->setName(\AuthorizeConstants::sandboxID);  // loginID / sandboxID
    $merchantAuthentication->setTransactionKey(\AuthorizeConstants::sandboxKey);  // loginKey / sandboxKey
    
    // Set the transaction's refId
    $refId = 'ref' . time();
    
    // Set order information
    $order = new AnetAPI\OrderType();
    $order->setInvoiceNumber($ss['invoiceID']);
    if (strpos($ii['invName'], "S") !== false) {
      $invDesc = $ii['servMonth']. " bill for Site " .$ii['venue'] ;
    } else if (strpos($ii['invName'], "R") !== false) {
      $invDesc = $ii['servMonth']. " bill for Region " .$ii['venue'] ;
    } else {
      $invDesc = $ii['servMonth']. " bill for " .$ii['venue'] ;
    }
    $order->setDescription($invDesc);    
    
    // Set the customer's identifying information
    $customerData = new AnetAPI\CustomerDataType();
    $customerData->setType("business");
    $customerData->setId($ii['cID']);
    $customerData->setEmail($ii['cEmail']);
    
    // Set the Bill To info for new payment type
    $billTo = new AnetAPI\CustomerAddressType();
    $billTo->setFirstName($ii['cFirstName']);
    $billTo->setLastName($ii['cLastName']);
    $billTo->setCompany($ii['cName']);
    $billTo->setAddress($ii['cAddress']. " " .$ii['cAddress1']);
    $billTo->setCity($ii['cCity']);
    $billTo->setState($ii['cState']);
    $billTo->setZip($ii['cZip']);
    $billTo->setCountry("USA");
    //$billTo->setFaxNumber('8005551212') ;
    //$billTo->setPhoneNumber($ii['cPhone']);
    
    // set shipping profile
    $shippingProfiles[] = $billTo ;
    
    //create a transaction
    $transactionRequestType = new AnetAPI\TransactionRequestType();
    $transactionRequestType->setTransactionType("authCaptureTransaction");
    $transactionRequestType->setAmount($ss['balance']);
    $transactionRequestType->setCustomer($customerData) ;
    $transactionRequestType->setOrder($order) ;
    if (isSet($ss['authMerchID'])) {
      $profileType = new AnetAPI\CustomerProfilePaymentType();
      $profileType->setCustomerProfileId($ss['authMerchID']) ;
      $transactionRequestType->setProfile($profileType) ;
    } else {
      $transactionRequestType->setBillTo($billTo) ;
      $transactionRequestType->setShipTo($billTo) ;
    }

    // Set Hosted Form options
    $setting0 = new AnetAPI\SettingType();
    $setting0->setSettingName("hostedPaymentReturnOptions");
    $setting0->setSettingValue( "{ \"url\": \"https://portal.mysdomain.com/adminInvoicePaid.html\", \"cancelUrl\": \"https://portal.mydomain.com/adminInvoicePay.html?invID=" .$ss['invoiceID']. "\", \"showReceipt\":true }" );
    
    $setting1 = new AnetAPI\SettingType();
    $setting1->setSettingName("hostedPaymentButtonOptions");
    $setting1->setSettingValue("{ \"text\": \"Submit Payment\" }");

    $setting2 = new AnetAPI\SettingType();
    $setting2->setSettingName("hostedPaymentStyleOptions");
    $setting2->setSettingValue("{ \"bgColor\": \"#192a67\" }");

    $setting3 = new AnetAPI\SettingType();
    $setting3->setSettingName("hostedPaymentPaymentOptions");
    $setting3->setSettingValue("{ \"cardCodeRequired\":true, \"showCreditCard\":true, \"showBankAccount\":true }");
    
    $setting4 = new AnetAPI\SettingType();
    $setting4->setSettingName("hostedPaymentShippingAddressOptions");
    $setting4->setSettingValue("{ \"show\":false, \"required\":true }");
    
    $setting5 = new AnetAPI\SettingType();
    $setting5->setSettingName("hostedPaymentBillingAddressOptions");
    $setting5->setSettingValue("{ \"show\":true, \"required\":true }");
    
    $setting6 = new AnetAPI\SettingType();
    $setting6->setSettingName("hostedPaymentCustomerOptions");
    $setting6->setSettingValue("{ \"showEmail\":true, \"requiredEmail\":true, \"addPaymentProfile\":false }");
    
    $setting7 = new AnetAPI\SettingType();
    $setting7->setSettingName("hostedPaymentOrderOptions");
    $setting7->setSettingValue("{ \"show\":false }");
    
    $setting8 = new AnetAPI\SettingType();
    $setting8->setSettingName("hostedPaymentIFrameCommunicatorUrl");
    $setting8->setSettingValue("{ \"url\": \"https://portal.mydomain.com/adminInvoiceFrame.html\" }");

    // Build transaction request
    $request = new AnetAPI\GetHostedPaymentPageRequest();
    $request->setMerchantAuthentication($merchantAuthentication);
    $request->setRefId($refId);
    $request->setTransactionRequest($transactionRequestType);

    $request->addToHostedPaymentSettings($setting0);
    $request->addToHostedPaymentSettings($setting1);
    $request->addToHostedPaymentSettings($setting2);
    $request->addToHostedPaymentSettings($setting3);
    $request->addToHostedPaymentSettings($setting4);
    $request->addToHostedPaymentSettings($setting5);
    $request->addToHostedPaymentSettings($setting6);
    $request->addToHostedPaymentSettings($setting7);
    $request->addToHostedPaymentSettings($setting8);

    //execute request
    $controller = new AnetController\GetHostedPaymentPageController($request);
    $response = $controller->executeWithApiResponse(\net\authorize\api\constants\ANetEnvironment::SANDBOX);
    
    $gToken=[] ;
    if (($response != null) && ($response->getMessages()->getResultCode() == "Ok")) {
        //echo $response->getToken()."\n";
        $gToken["Error"]  = 0 ;
        $gToken["Token"] = $response->getToken() ;
    } else {
        //echo "ERROR :  Failed to get hosted payment page token\n";
        $errorMessages = $response->getMessages()->getMessage();
        //echo "RESPONSE : " . $errorMessages[0]->getCode() . "  " .$errorMessages[0]->getText() . "\n";
        $gToken["Error"]  = 1 ;
        $gToken["errMsg"] = $errorMessages[0]->getCode() . ":  " .$errorMessages[0]->getText() ;
    }
    return array($gToken,$request);
}
```

*** UPDATE***

Looking at the network console logs, there is a request going out to `https://test.authorize.net/payment/payment` - but the key `token` is empty, which would appear to be the reason for the error `Missing or Invalid Token`.  In my form, I can validate the TOKEN is there.  But when I click the `trigger popup iFrame` button, I can visually see the `token` being deleted from the hidden form field.

Answer (score 1):

The code to open the popup iframe, copied verbatim from the Authorize.net code sample had this bit of code `$("#popupToken").val($("#inputtoken").val());`  - this is erasing/deleting the token value before it was being submitted to payment gateway - what the heck?!  Why would their own example code do that?  Commenting this out fixed it.

```
AuthorizeNetPopup.openPopup = function () {
  var popup = document.getElementById("divAuthorizeNetPopup");
  var popupScreen = document.getElementById("divAuthorizeNetPopupScreen");
  var ifrm = document.getElementById("iframeAuthorizeNet");
  var form = document.forms["formAuthorizeNetPopup"];
  //$("#popupToken").val($("#inputtoken").val());   // WTH authorize????
  form.action = "https://test.authorize.net/payment/payment";
  ifrm.style.width = "442px";
  ifrm.style.height = "578px";

  form.submit();

  popup.style.display = "";
  popupScreen.style.display = "";
  centerPopup();
  };
```